# HTML image vertical align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using HTML, CSS and Jquery and I did a image hover effect with the watch image and I want to be able to add the same image and effect with multiple images vertically down the center of the page but it wont let me, here's the site in question! any help would be great!

```
<div id="header">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
<div class="center12">
    <img src="image/logocenter1.png" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **">
</div>
<div id="nav">
    <h2>
        <a href="index.html" class="rollover">Home</a> / <a href="style.html"   class="rollover">Styles & Sizes</a> / 
        <a href="brand.html" class="rollover">Brands & Prices</a> / 
        <a href="strap.html" class="rollover">Watch Straps</a> / <a href="used.html" class="rollover">Tips on buying used</a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="fadehover">
    <img src="image/test1.png" alt="" class="a"> <img src="image/test1bw.png" alt="" class="b">
</div>
```

It seems like it should be simple, but it wont work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here, there's only one image area, and what are you trying to vertically align?

Comment: I want to be able to put this over and over and over with different images and have the same effect <div class="fadehover"><img src="image/test1.png" alt="" class="a"> <img src="image/test1bw.png" alt="" class="b"></div>

Comment: Ok, so where's the JS you're using?

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>

Comment: The html on this url is correct (designriot.net/wnm250/module-15/index3.html). Now only put jquery script to change image on hover by maintaining relationship between them.

Comment: in other words, is there something wrong with this to not let me put it over and over down the page? <div class="fadehover"><img src="image/test1.png" alt="" class="a"> <img src="image/test1bw.png" alt="" class="b"></div>

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of using jquery and two images for gray scale effect, use the following:

By adding an css you can bring the same effect using a single image(no need of jquery and hover image).

Add this css:

<pre>
img.a:hover {
    filter: url("");
   }
</pre>

and remove the jquery and another gray scale image. If you don't want hover effect and the images are needs to be shown one by one down, remove one of the images inside the div and put it into a separate Div'
```

Comment: I would but its a class project and it needs to have jquery on the site.

Comment: do you want image with hover effect one by one down? or multiple images behind?

Comment: you can do this with single image using jquery like below:

Comment: sorry forgot to add :)

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).css("filter", "url("")");
});

});
</script>